# Why can't we set first responder in makeUIView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was just looking at some sample code for making a TextField that automatically opens the keyboard using first responder status in SwiftUI, and I was wondering why we can't just set textField.becomeFirstResponder() in makeUIView(). It seems like most of the code samples I've been finding have that in updateUIView(), with the coordinator tracking to make sure becomeFirstResponder() is only called once. Is there a problem doing it the first way?

Comment: Because view it is not in view hierarchy there yet, only created.

Comment: Ahhh I see, thank you!

Comment: View does not exist yet when this method is invoked. And also the system calls this method only once, when it creates your view for the first time, meaning if you leave the screen and comeback to it the becomeFirstResponderwill not be invoked if it is placed in makeUIView, of course it is a problem only if this is a usecase

Comment: Ahh thank you for the detailed explanation.